# How to check if a function is anonymous in R

Tags: r

I want to write a function that distinguishes if a function is being sourced from a package or set up anonymously in a case where these are the only 2 possibilities (constraints of a one-liner).

If it's the latter - let's call it a variable `anonymous.function` - I'd want to 'get it out' of the `(function(parameters){inner_workings})` closure as `function(){}` by `eval(parse(text = call(anonymous.function()))`

- `typeof(package::function)` returns "closure"
- `typeof((function(parameters) {inner_workings}))` likewise returns "closure"

Should I distinguish the two by comparing `environment`, or `namespace`?

- `environment(package::function)` returns `<environment: namespace:package>`
- `environment((function)parameters) {inner_workings}))` returns `<environment: R_GlobalEnv>`

I'm hesitant to say that I'll only assume it's anonymous if environment is GlobalEnv, as the stack could be traversed below Global if I understand correctly in some situations, e.g. if I'm running this function within a function, so I'd check if environment is a namespace.

Can anyone tell me how I can check for a namespace? I can see it in the reported string as `<environment: namespace:...>` but can't seem to access that distinction. The only distinction I can see is that a namespace environment isn't hashed - that's only observed upon failing to run `env.profile()` for an unhashed environment...

Surely there's a simple way to check for anonymous functions without a try/catch statement! :-) Advice would be greatly appreciated, the R documentation seems to run dry at this level.

**Edit** ideally accessing the data structure, i.e. without `grepl`ing a string!

Comment: If the function is passed as a parameter, you could use `deparse(substitute(fun))` and `grepl` for `"function("`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does `packageName` work for you? I was unsure about the desired output of a function like `f1 <- mean`. See below for my version.

```
is_package_fun <- function(fun) 
  !is.null(packageName(environment(fun)))

# defining functions
f1 <- mean
f2 <- function(x) mean(x)

# checking
is_package_fun(mean)
## [1] TRUE
is_package_fun(f1) # not sure about desired output...
## [1] TRUE
is_package_fun(f2)
## [1] FALSE
```